# How can I populate nested array objects in mongoDB or mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have an `orders` collection where each `order` has the following shape:

```
  {
    "_id": "5252875356f64d6d28000001",
    "lineItems": [
      { productId: 'prod_007', quantity: 3 }, 
      { productId: 'prod_003', quantity: 2 }
    ]
    // other fields omitted
  }
```

I also have a `products` collection, where each `product` contains a unique `productId` field.

How can I populate each `lineItem.productId` with a matching `product` from the `products` collection? Thanks! :)

EDIT: `orderSchema` and `productSchema`:

```
const orderSchema = new Schema({
  checkoutId: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  customerId: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  lineItems: {
    type: [itemSubSchema],
    required: true,
  },
});

const itemSubSchema = new Schema(
  {
    productId: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    quantity: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  { _id: false }
);

const productSchema = new Schema({
  productId: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  imageURL: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0, 
  },
});
```

Comment: Can you post your schema as well?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact output you want but I think this is what you are looking for:

The trick here is to use [$lookup](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) in an aggregation stage.

- First `$unwind` to deconstruct the array and can merge each id with the other collection.
- Then the `$lookup` itself. This is like a join in SQL. It merges the desired objects with same ids.
- Then recreate the population using `$mergeObjects` to get properties from both collections.
- And last re-group objects to get the array again.

```
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$lineItems"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "products",
      "localField": "lineItems.productId",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "result"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "lineItems": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$lineItems",
          {
            "$first": "$result"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "lineItems": {
        "$push": "$lineItems"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/w1xQBthLI-x)

With this query you have the same intial data but "filled" with the values from the other collection.

Edit: You can also avoid one stage, maybe it is clear with the `$set` stage but [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mNGt-FDBOQH) do the same as it merge the objects in the `$group` stage while pushing to the array.

Comment: Hi thanks for responding. My first concern is, given that no $match is applied, won't the initial $unwind operation unwind every single `lineItems` array in every single order? Is that really efficient, especially if I have 1000 orders, for example?

Comment: Yes, that's true, without `$match` it will do along all the collection. So if you can use `$match` is better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Mongoose populate method either when you query your documents or as middleware. However, Mongoose only allows normal population on the `_id` field.

```
const itemSubSchema = new Schema({
  product: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'productSchema',
  }
});

const order = await orderSchema.find().populate('lineItems.$*.product');
// special populate syntax necessary for nested documents
```

Using middleware you would still need to reconfigure your item schema to save the `_id` from products. But this method would automatically call populate each time you query items:

```
itemSubSchema.pre('find', function(){
  this.populate('product');
});
```

You could also declare your item schema within your order schema to reduce one layer of joining data:

```
const orderSchema = new Schema({
 lineItems: [{
  type: {
   quantity: {type: Number, required: true},
   product: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: 'productSchema',   
   }
  },
  required: true,
 }]
});

const orders = orderSchema.find().populate('lineItems');
```